# Udev rules do not work while a USB device is plugged in

Tags: linux, usb, udev

I am trying to disable all USB ports and only provide access to my keyboard and mouse.

Rules are working when I plug in and out the USB devices. 
However,
when I try to reboot the system while there is a plugged-in USB device,
after the reboot the system reads the USB device that shouldn't be accessible.

How can I fix this situation?

My rules are these:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'for host in /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*; do echo 0 > $host/authorized_default; done'"

ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="0461" , ATTR{idProduct}=="0010" , RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 1 >/sys$DEVPATH/authorized'"

ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="17ef" , ATTR{idProduct}=="608d" , RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 1 >/sys$DEVPATH/authorized'"
```